# Buffer Server C

Tags: c, sockets, server, buffer

I have been trying this server code in c, it works properly for the first time. But when a client calls it for the second time the buffer remains with the values of the previous message of the client, and the values of the second message are overwritten on it.

*e.g.* First message is `Hello`, and the second message is `Hi`, the buffer will be `Hillo`. How can I fix it?

```
/*
    C socket server example, handles multiple clients using threads
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write
#include<pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread
 int i;
//the thread function

void *connection_handler(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8080 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message , client_message[];



    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        //Send the message back to client
        write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));


    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }


    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new_sock = malloc(1);` should be `new_sock = malloc(sizeof client_sock);`. Otherwise you're into undefined behaviour on the next line `*new_sock = client_sock;`.

Comment: OT: Define `c` to be of `socklen_t` and remove the cast to `socklen_t*` in the call to `accept()`.

Comment: OT: Also `recv()` returns `ssize_t` *not* `int`.

Comment: `char  client_message[];` does not allocate a buffer to read to. In fact it's the same as `char *client_message;` Using it like this provokes undefined behaviour. Do `char client_message[2000];` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `strlen(client_message)`, use `read_size`. That's how many bytes you got, so that's how many bytes you send.

The problem is that the message doesn't have a NUL terminator at the end, so `strlen` doesn't work. To put a NUL terminator at the end of the message, do this:

```
client_message[read_size] = '\0';
```

Then you can use `client_message` with functions that take a string, like `strlen`, `printf`, `puts`, etc.

But if all you're doing is echoing the message back to the sender, you don't need to bother with the NUL terminator.

Answer (score 1):

```
while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
{
    //Send the message back to client
    write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));


}
```

Usual mistake. You're assuming that `recv()` filled the buffer. This is an echo server, so you should only echo what you actually received:

```
while( (read_size = recv(sock, client_message, sizeof client_message, 0)) > 0 )
{
    //Send the message back to client
    write(sock , client_message , read_size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [memset](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm) function clear the buffer before receiving  messages.

```
memset(client_message,'\0', sizeof(client_message));
```

Comment: Why? It's only necessarty to observe the byte count actually received. This sort of thing is just cargo-cult programming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, `strlen()` keeps counting until it finds a null byte.

The second message that you recieved does not have a null byte to terminate it. So, `strlen()` will return a number "x" which is the distance of the next null byte. That means, your program will write "x" bytes instead of just the message.

To fix this, you can just pass `read_size` to the `write()` function, or, if you want to continue to use `strlen()`, set `client_message[read_size]` to `'\0'`.